# Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes' & { className?: string | undefined; }'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple screen where I use some custom components, but I'm having problems with a ts error:

`Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { className?: string | undefined; }'.`

in this file where I import my `ContentCenterDiv` component:

```
import LoadingIndicator from './LoadingIndicator';
import ErrorIndicator from './ErrorIndicator';
import React from 'react';
import ContentCenterDiv from './ContentCenterDiv';

export default function LoadingAndErrorCentered({ isLoading, isError, error }: { isLoading: boolean, isError: boolean, error: any }) {
    return (
        <ContentCenterDiv>
            <LoadingIndicator isLoading={isLoading} />
            <ErrorIndicator isError={isError} error={error} />
        </ContentCenterDiv>
    );
}
```

ContentCenterDiv.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

export default function ContentCenterDiv({ className, ...others }: { className?: string }) {
    return <div {...others} className={`w-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center ${className}`} />;
}
```

To be clear, `ContentCenterDiv` is a 'container', that means, it's the parent element of one or more components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the props type `{ className?: string }` you specify that `ContentCenterDiv` has no other props than `className`, which means it also doesn't have a `children` prop and therefore won't accept children.

You can either manually specify a `children?: ReactNode` property in the parameter type, or use the generic type `React.PropsWithChildren` type to add it:

```
function ContentCenterDiv({ className, ...others }:
  PropsWithChildren<{ className?: string }>) {
    return <div {...others} className={`w-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center ${className}`} />;
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecAKUEYAzgOrAwAWAwlcADYAmUSAdnAL5wBmRIcAOSt0MQQChxaCGxLwAMhBRNgbAOYBJNirQoY0OAF44ACjBFSALjgo2ATwCURgHxwAPCoBuztwHovzlIycnAAolBEUFo6egbGZhYk1raOLu4BfgGSSAAekLBwTEg8KACuDPA8pWwYwDJwisqqagCC2uGRNOwwSKxMJnjAJI0q6thDHdDYvZFc1oPDSqNq1gBGEBAMqGzjJJNQaxtbttMR0Mn2XE444nB3cKwwpVAcJrf3H240Mj1sMF1-XoAEWA3neHwh7hGzWiwF0+igcCG0PUhhwyKWzW4vkCkMhbn2sPhBgmZygaNJkW4M2gaJpUGxuLxfm+gL+AJ6UBBYI+DgA3OJOJIqjUYHUOKzfv9usDQQM4GgGCgSCQAHIoEBIbAAOl1EGovRIcwIiQo1DojBY7DceEVyrVGqQAH5rHIoM0uM5ruCHkgni90qDcLrtfqqIbuHaVerNWiAAYAdwAtABGAAMacKSZ4WxyvFzSekDFKIA4KAYwDUbCTlCQIBIhZliIAJDgow7NZw44yBUKgA)